# checkbox style is missing when form is submitted and angular scope variable is refreshed

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, stylesheet

I have an application which uses **[charisma template 1.x](https://github.com/usmanhalalit/charisma/tree/1.x)**, I have now used AngularJS within the template. The application is working fine but the problem is that I am having a Tab Grid within which there is a form with submit window. In each Group Tab I am having n number of checkboxes, after clicking some of the checkboxes when I click the submit button, a particular `ng-submit` action is performed apart from the form action I am trying to refresh the scope values like as given below

```
$scope.records = angular.copy($scope.recordCopy);
```

The functionality is working fine but the style of the checkbox is lost, A sample mockup is shown in the plunker, there before clicking the save notice the style of checkbox, after clicking the save button you can see the style of the checkbox is gone, but still the functionality is working fine.

Can anyone please tell me some solution for retaining the checkbox style

Browser: Firefox

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/s94LquuQNAISRumbMgKz?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know why exactly the style of the checkbox is lost.

But it desappears because your using of angular.copy is wrong.

Please see the definition of the function copy here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

```
angular.copy(source, [destination]);
```

Your code becomes :

```
 angular.copy($scope.recordCopy,$scope.records);
```

I hope my answer fit you.